# LS and ES monitorign

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i am using EL and LS of the same version 5.4.0 and filbeat version 5.4.1.there is the configuration.
--------------elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: node1
node.attr.rack: r1
path.data: /path/to/data
path.logs: /path/to/logs
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["127.0.0.1:9200", "127.0.0.1:9200"]
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

----------filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.prospectors:
input_type: log
paths:
- c:\logstash-tutorial.log
output.logstash:
hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

--------------pipeline.conf-----

```
input {
beats {
port => "5044"
}
}
filter {
grok {
match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
}
geoip {
source => "clientip"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts =>"localhost:9200"
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Note:the LS and ES are runing at the port 6900 and 9200 well.but i get those errors:
for filebeat: ERR Connecting error publishing events (retrying): dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5044: connectex: Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée.
for logstash:error=>"Got response code '503' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://localhost:9200/
Please how can i solve this probleme?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind to **127.0.0.1:9200** instead of localhost, maybe:

```
output {
elasticsearch {
    hosts =>"127.0.0.1:9200"
}
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ugosan for your answer.i try it.it diplays
 
`'name: "node1", cluster_name: "elasticsearch", cluster_uuid: "kKbMy9_LRw-CcELir6KcFQ", version: { number: "5.4.0", build_hash: "780f8c4", build_date: "2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z", build_snapshot: false, lucene_version: "6.5.0" }, tagline: "You Know, for Search"`

so my question is how to dispay the content of the file parsed.

Comment: You have to use Kibana for that

Comment: Yeh,but how can i consume the data by Java?

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXtH_BhxdgA

Comment: Thank you @ugosan for help.